# Complex Conjugate of Schrodinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

I read from Griffith's Introduction to Quantum Mechanics that:

> Now the Schrodinger equation says that,
>   $$\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\,\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi\tag{1.23}$$
>   and hence also (taking the complex conjugate of Equation 1.23)
>   $$\frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial t}=-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\,\frac{\partial^2\Psi^*}{\partial x^2}+\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi^*.\tag{1.24}$$

How is 1.24 arrived from 1.23? What is the math rule that was used?

Comment: Like it says, take the complex conjugate of each side of the equation

Comment: @BySymmetry why was there a sign change on the right side and not on the left side?

Comment: When taking the complex conjugate $i \rightarrow i^*=-i$ and $\psi \rightarrow \psi^*$

Comment: The [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) is an operation that puts a minus sign only in the imaginary part of a complex number.

Comment: Please don't paste images of text and formulae, instead you should copy it into the post so it can be properly indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The conjugate of the product of two numbers is the product of their conjugates:

$$ (uv)^* = u^* v^* $$

So:

$$ \left( \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} \right)^* = i^* \left( \frac{\hbar}{2m} \right)^* \left( \frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2} \right)^*  = -i \frac{\hbar}{2m} \frac{\partial^2\psi^*}{\partial x^2} $$

Likewise:

$$ \left(\frac{iV}{\hbar}\psi\right)^* = i^* \left(\frac{V}{\hbar}\right)^* \psi^* = -i \frac{V}{\hbar}\psi^* $$

Comment: For completeness you might need to add that complex conjugate of x-derivative is derivative of complex conjugate (applied on $\psi$).

Comment: Also, it seems that $\hbar$ and not $h$ should be in the denominator of the RHS (last line).